# why my hypgraph (headless cms service) data is not appearing in my project production

Tags: next.js, graphql, hygraph

when I am working with my NextJS project using Hygraph, deployment environment is good for this once I post new article  but not visible in production environment

I tried to refresh the page but not visible again,
how to display my graphql data on production environment